# Avoid escape characters in paste0 when printing double quotation marks

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I am writing a script to enter a formula into an openxlsx excel sheet using writeFormula. For the function, I need to specify a formula vector of length equal to number of cells.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
for(i in 2:(nrow(data)+1)){formula_dep<-append(formula_dep, paste0("IFERROR(SEARCH(\"pack\",H",i,"))"))}
writeFormula(wb=file, sheet="data", x=formula_dep, startCol=9, startRow=2)
```

In the output, the escape characters are probably getting printed into the excel sheet and thus it is getting corrupted (I have to repair to open the file, where the column has nothing in it).

In R, the output is (as usual):

```
"IFERROR(SEARCH(\"pack\",H2))"
```

While the escape characters are not a problem in many other tasks, in this one, I cannot make this work. I cannot use single quote as for some unknown reason Excel does not allow that in FIND or SEARCH functions (regex issues maybe). Please help with the solution here.

Note: I cannot just inculcate the formula in the dataframe itself (using R formulae) as it is supposed to work on user inputs in the excel file itself.

I am open to solutions both from Excel side (changing the formula while doing the same thing), or from R side.

Comment: Same issue with IFS function in excel, for some reason, it does not accept single quotes as well.

Comment: Try: `cat("IFERROR(SEARCH(\"pack\",H2))")` "\" is not there, it just shows it is escaping the "

Comment: Also, there is no need for forloop. `paste0("IFERROR(SEARCH(\"pack\",H", 2:(nrow(data)+1), "))")` would do the same as forloop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"\"` is not there, it just shows that *print* is escaping the `"`, see:

```
cat("IFERROR(SEARCH(\"pack\",H2))")
# IFERROR(SEARCH("pack",H2))
```

Here is a working example:

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")

df <- data.frame(
  a = letters[1:3],
)

writeData(wb, sheet = 1, x = df)

f <- paste0("FIND(\"b\",A", seq(nrow(df)) + 1L, ")")

f[ 1 ]
#[1] "FIND(\"b\",A2)"

cat(f[ 1 ])
# FIND("b",A2)

writeFormula(wb, sheet ="Sheet 1", x = f, startCol = 2, startRow = 2)

saveWorkbook(wb, "writeFormulaExample.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: This works. But I am getting #NAME? error in the formula column in the one I am trying to print, yours work flawlessly. Any idea why that might be?
My formula also works if just open the excel, start editing the cell and press enter without changing anything.

Comment: @Arani As you can see my example works. Please provide reproducible set up: provide example data and the code that produces formulas, and code used to output the excel file that would have `#NAME?` issue. Then we can help you further.

Comment: formula_dep <- paste0("IFERROR(INDEX(issues!D:D, MATCH($G",rows,", issues!$A:$A, 0)), IFS(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(\"packed\", H",rows,")), \"warehouse & LP\", ISNUMBER(SEARCH(\"not process\", H",rows,")), \"warehouse\", TRUE, \"check\"))", sep="")